# Turning a 10 A, 24 V signal on/off with a 5 V signal

Tags: transistors, switches, relay

I'm currently working on an electrical power steering (EPS) system for an electric vehicle. The motor, which will assist the driver, is this [stepper motor](https://www.moonsindustries.com/p/am-series-hybrid-stepper-motors-with-encoder/am34hd1404-e1000d-000004611110010633). The motor will be controlled by this [stepper driver](https://www.moonsindustries.com/p/st-series-two-phase-dc-stepper-motor-drives/msst10-c-ce-000004696351000065).
The stepper driver will be powered by a 24 V line, and outputs a maximum of 10 A. For safety reasons (in case of any errors in the system) I would like to able to cut the power to the driver, thus turning the system off.

The solutions seems to be either a transistor or a relay, however I've ran into some issues regarding both approaches.

For a transistor I'm a bit concerned about the dissipated power, both in terms of heat (though I imagine this can be fixed with a heatsink), but also in terms of power that simply goes to waste. As mentioned the vehicle is electric, and as such the EPS-system will be powered from the car's battery. The vehicle is a fairly small racecar with limited battery capacity (I don't have the accept number at this time), and I would very much prefer if I could keep any unnecessary power consumption at a minimum.

A relay seems to be a more power friendly solution, however I am uncertain if they can deliver the current I need. Take for example this [relay](https://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf), which can deliver 10 A, 28 VDC to a resistive load, but only 5 A, 28 VDC to an inductive load. The relay would be directly connected to the motor driver, however since the driver is connected to the stepper motor, is it then correct to assume that the motor is the real load, and thus the relay is connected to an inductive load? In that case this relay wouldn't work. I've found other relays that can deliver the desired current, but they require more than 5 V to trigger, which is not an option, since the logic signal which turns it on or off is only 5 V.

It's very possible there is a third option that I have not even considered.

In advance I would like to first apologize if this is not the correct site for such a question, but also to thank anyone who can provide some insight.

Comment: What made you think the dissipated power would be too much if using a transistor?

Comment: @Andyaka Truth be told I've possibly been overestimating the issue, however in any case I would prefer to keep any power dissipation at a minimum, which made a transistor seem like it wouldn't be the ideal solution.

Comment: And what about relay coil power dissipation? How can you ignore that? Chances are it will be not be less than the conduction losses of a decent MOSFET.

Comment: @Andyaka I have no idea how I missed this. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: You can probably get a MOSFET with on-resistance of 0.003 ohms and, with 10 amps flowing, the power dissipation will be 300 mW. I bet the relay will be about that or a bit more.

Comment: Several specifications are missing to complete such a design: supply characteristics (especially voltage range and possible transients), load characteristics (the links are broken), and any further useful information such as available size, power dissipation, operating temperature, environmental conditions, etc. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Use a small transistor to switch a conventional 24V automotive relay, the motors are not a conventional inductive load as the motor driver has freewheeling diodes built in to it to handle the inductive spikes, as well as local decoupling. if anything it would be a slightly capacitive load, but in most cases that helps keep the relay contacts clean.

Do not forget to include a protection diode in anti-parallel with the transistor C-E, so when the relay spikes when switched off, it does not hurt the transistor.